# Handlebars: Compiling template with nested iterators

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm trying to create a glossary of terms using Handlebars.  Each term contains an array of related terms.  If I try to use the `{{ #each }}` style syntax I get an error.  If I just use `{{ related }}` it converts each item in the array to a string.  I need to get at each element individually so I can wrap it in a span with a class for style.

**Data:**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Habitat",
    "description": "The place in nature with distinct features (such as short grass, wet ground, dry rocks, etc.) that an animal calls home because it provides what it needs to survive: food, water and shelter.",
    "related": ["range", "habitat fragmentation"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Habitat fragmentation",
    "description": "When an animal’s homeland or range is split up into smaller pieces. <br><br>For example, if we place a road in the middle of a large field, we have fragmented the field into two pieces. If any animal’s den is on one side of the road and its food is on the other, the animal must now take the risk of crossing the road in order to survive.",
    "related": ["habitat"]
  }
]
```

**Template**:

```
<script id="glossary-template" type="x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each .}}
  <li class="term">
    <h3>{{ name }} {{ acronym }}</h3>
    <p>{{{ description }}}</p>
    <p>Related Terms:{{ #related }}<span class="tag">{{this}}<span>{{ /related }}
  </li>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here was that I was using two unnamed iterators.  I passed my data to the compiled template as a named parameter, and everything works now.

```
$('ul').append(template({"terms": data}));


<script id="glossary-template" type="x-handlebars-template">
  {{#terms}}
  <li class="term">
    <h3>{{ name }} {{ acronym }}</h3>
    <p>{{{ description }}}</p>
    {{#related}}<span class="tag">{{this}}</span>{{/related}}
  </li>
  {{/terms}}
</script>
```

Comment: If this answered your question, then please accept it as the answer.